# W3 Total Cache PDF Preview is displayed as text

Tags: wordpress, plugins, fpdf, w3-total-cache

I have a W3 total cache plugin installed in Wordpress. I have managed to minify CSS and js scripts but I have a PDF generator which generates data from posts. When deactivating the plugin, it can generate PDF but when the plugin is activated it displays in the browser like the image below:

[image]

I use fpdf to generate PDF. Below is my code to generate the PDF:

```
    $pdf = new PDF();
    // Column headings
    $header = array('Lot', 'Estate', 'Suburb', 'Land Size', 'House Name','Package Price','Est. Titles');

    // Data loading
    $post_data = get_recent_properties();

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetMargins(5,5,5);
    $pdf->BasicTable($header,$post_data);
    $pdf->Output();
```

I also reset W3 total cache settings but still PDF not previewing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable (un-check) `Enable HTTP (gzip) compression` in Browser cache settings.